# C double linked list insertion sort memory fault

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I wanted to implement insertion sort on `dl_list` containing `char*` values but I got a segmentation fault after running program (no warnings, I use gcc).

This is my structure:

```
struct node;

typedef struct node {
    char *name;
    char *surname;
    char *birth_date;
    char *email;
    char *phone;
    char *address;

    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
} node;

//doubly linked_list
typedef struct dl_list {  
    node *head;
    node *tail;
} dl_list;
```

I sort it by surname, later name. When values are same it return 0, if alpha should be before beta it return -1, otherwise 1:

```
int compare(node *alpha, node *beta) {
    int a_surn_len = strlen(alpha->surname);
    int b_surn_len = strlen(beta->surname);

    for (int i = 0; i < ((a_surn_len > b_surn_len) ? b_surn_len : a_surn_len); i += 1) {
        if (alpha->surname[i] > beta->surname[i]) return 1;
        if (alpha->surname[i] < beta->surname[i]) return -1;
        //if (alpha->surname[i] == beta->surname[i]) continue; 
    }
    if (a_surn_len != b_surn_len) return a_surn_len > b_surn_len ? 1 : -1;

    int a_n_len = strlen(alpha->name);
    int b_n_len = strlen(beta->name);
    for (int j = 0; j < ((a_n_len > b_n_len) ? b_n_len : a_n_len); j += 1) {
        if (alpha->name[j] > beta->name[j]) return 1;
        if (alpha->name[j] < beta->name[j]) return -1;
        //if (alpha->surname[i] == beta->surname[i]) continue;  
    }   
    if (a_n_len != b_n_len) return a_n_len > b_n_len ? 1 : -1;
    return 0;
}
```

And here insertion algorithm on my list:

```
dl_list *list_sort(dl_list *list) {
    // zero or one element in list
    if (list->head == NULL || list->tail == NULL)
        return list;
    // new_head is the first element of resulting sorted list
    node *new_head = NULL;
    while (list->head != NULL) {
        node *current = list->head;
        list->head = list->head->next;
        // insert the first element into an empty sorted list
        if (new_head == NULL) {
            current->next = new_head;
            new_head = current;
            new_head->prev = NULL;
        // or as the head of the sorted list
        } else
        if (compare(current, new_head) == -1) {
            current->next = new_head;
            new_head->prev = current;
            new_head = current;
            new_head->prev = NULL;
        } else {
            // insert current element into proper position in non-empty sorted list
            node *ptr = new_head;
            while (ptr != NULL) {
                // middle of the list
                if (compare(current, ptr->next) == -1) {
                    current->next = ptr->next;
                    ptr->next->prev = current;
                    ptr->next = current;
                    current->prev = ptr;
                    break; //done
                // last element of the sorted list
                } else
                if (ptr->next == NULL) {
                    current->next = ptr->next;
                    ptr->next = current;
                    current->prev = ptr;
                    break;//done                
                }
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }
        }
    }
    list->head = new_head;
    node *ptr2;
    for (ptr2 = list->head; ptr2->next != NULL; ptr2 = ptr2->next);
    list->tail = ptr2;

    return list;
}
```

I tried to check this code on paper and it seems to work fine, on some 4-5 elements lists.

Comment: Is there a main?  Don't know how some of these routines are called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the insertion loop: you must check if `ptr->next` is not `NULL` **before** comparing `current` with node `ptr->next`:

```
        // insert current element into proper position in non-empty sorted list
        node *ptr = new_head;
        while (ptr != NULL) {
            if (ptr->next == NULL) {
                current->next = ptr->next;
                ptr->next = current;
                current->prev = ptr;
                break;               
            } else
            if (compare(current, ptr->next) < 0) {
                current->next = ptr->next;
                ptr->next->prev = current;
                ptr->next = current;
                current->prev = ptr;
                break;
            }
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
```

You could also simplify the comparison function with `strcmp()`:

```
int compare(const node *alpha, const node *beta) {
    int res;

    if ((res = strcmp(alpha->surname, beta->surname)) != 0)
        return res;
    if ((res = strcmp(alpha->name, beta->name)) != 0)
        return res;
    return 0;
}
```

And you should just compare the return value with `0` instead of explicitly with `-1` or `1`.

Here is a simplified version:

```
dl_list *list_sort(dl_list *list) {
    // zero or one element in list
    if (list->head == NULL || list->tail == NULL)
        return list;
    // new_head is the first element of resulting sorted list
    node *new_head = NULL;
    while (list->head != NULL) {
        node *current = list->head;
        list->head = list->head->next;
        if (new_head == NULL) {
            // insert the first element into an empty sorted list
            current->prev = current->next = NULL;                
            new_head = current;
        } else
        if (compare(current, new_head) < 0) {
            // or as the head of the sorted list
            current->next = new_head;
            current->prev = NULL;
            new_head->prev = current;
            new_head = current;
        } else {
            // insert current element into proper position in non-empty sorted list
            node *ptr = new_head;
            while (ptr != NULL) {
                if (ptr->next == NULL) {
                    current->next = NULL;
                    ptr->next = current;
                    current->prev = ptr;
                    break;               
                } else
                if (compare(current, ptr->next) < 0) {
                    current->next = ptr->next;
                    ptr->next->prev = current;
                    ptr->next = current;
                    current->prev = ptr;
                    break;
                }
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }
        }
    }
    list->head = new_head;
    node *ptr2;
    for (ptr2 = list->head; ptr2->next != NULL; ptr2 = ptr2->next)
        continue;
    list->tail = ptr2;

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help. I thought about `strcmp()` but to be honest I wrongly understood how it works and thought it works on whole array no matter of indexes value order. :)

Comment: `strcmp(a,b)` does exactly what you do in your comparison function except it is much more efficient and the return value is `<0` if `a`is less then `b`, `==0` if `a` and `b` are equal and `>0` if `a` is greater than `b`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite long and it will be hard to debug without a minimal example. Maybe , you can compile with the -g flag and use valgrind. That tool will give you the line of the memory fault :)

Just use: `valgrind --track-origins=yes ./executable`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your insertion loop doesn't really make sense:

```
   node *new_head=NULL;
    while(list->head != NULL){
        node *current=list->head;
        list->head=list->head->next;
        // insert the first element into an empty sorted list
        if(new_head == NULL){
            current->next=new_head;
            new_head=current;
            new_head->prev=NULL;
```

1) You set `new_head` to be a pointer to `NULL`

2) You take keep a reference of `head` in `current` and make `head`=`head->next`

3) On your first loop `new_head` is still `NULL`, so you enter the if statement and set `current->next=new_head`.  But `new_head` points to `NULL`, so this causes problems!

4) Now when you set `new_head=current`, `current`/`new_head`'s `next` pointer points to `NULL`.

5) Finally you set `new_head->prev` to `NULL`, meaning that now `current`/`new_head` point to `NULL` in both directions, but your loop is waiting for `list->head` to be `NULL`!  This never happens, so once you've done an iteration and try to move forward you end up in your else block

```
  } else{
        // insert current element into proper position in non-empty sorted list
        node *ptr=new_head;
        while(ptr != NULL){
            // middle of the list
            if(compare(current, ptr->next) == -1){
                current->next=ptr->next;
                ptr->next->prev=current;
                ptr->next=current;
                current->prev=ptr;
                break; //done
            // last element of the sorted list
            } else if(ptr->next == NULL ){
                current->next=ptr->next;
                ptr->next=current;
                current->prev=ptr;
                break;//done                
            }
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
    }
```

6) This block tries to compare `current` to `new_head->next`.  But `new_head->next` is `NULL`!

Comment: Point 1-5 aren't problem if I understood you good. Look. dl_list looks like it: `NULL<-head<->node<->...<->tail->NULL`. It is intended to `new_head` points on `NULL` in both directions when it is FIRST element. `list->head` traverse on entry list from which I take elements one by one, where is problem here? Point 6, you are right I haven't thought about that case. I think no matter which `if` will be first in this loop there should be another conditional to prevent leak.